# Salesforce lightning Aura Component error

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I have a Lightning Aura component that is added on the Opportunity record detail page. When I update an Opportunity record and refresh the page, the below error pops up.

> Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [Value is not a string, ObjectId, or FieldId.]
>
> throws at https://xxxinstance.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/dOMRLHt4yryfVjId3qhSww/aura_prod.js:43:15. Caused by: Error in $A.getCallback() [Value is not a string, ObjectId, or FieldId.]

[image]

I see the console log and even after enabling Lightning debug mode, I don't see any error in the console and neither in the debug logs.

Comment: What code are you using in `$A.getCallback()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var action = component.get("c.getChecklist");        
        action.setParams({
            "recordId" : component.get("v.recordId")
        });        
        action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
            if (a.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
                if(component.isValid()) {
                    var returnValue = a.getReturnValue();
                    if(returnValue != null){

                    else{                         

                    }                        
                }
            }
        });             
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
```